# Adding a tooltip for html.dropdownlist

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, razor

I am working on an asp.net mvc web application. i have the following code which create a viewBag that contains a list of servers:-

```
 ViewBag.Servers = repository.AllServer().Where(a => a.TechnologyRole.Name.ToLower() == "hypervisor").ToList();
```

and inside my view i am displaying a drop-down that contains the viewBag items as follow:-

```
 @Html.DropDownListFor(model =>model.VirtualMachine.ServerID, ((IEnumerable<TMS.Models.TMSServer>)ViewBag.Servers).Select(option => new SelectListItem {
        Text = (option == null ? "None" : option.Technology.Tag), 
        Value = option.TMSServerID.ToString(),
        Selected = (Model != null) && (Model.VirtualMachine != null) && (option.TMSServerID == Model.VirtualMachine.ServerID)
    }), "Choose...")
```

currently i need to display extra information for the drop down items , and display them inside tooltips. so can anyone advice what is the best way to do so ?
Thanks

Comment: All the Razor helpers do is just generate HTML, and since there's no way to do this with straight HTML, there's no way to do it with a Razor helper. It's going to require custom JavaScript or some existing third-party JavaScript library, which is pretty much all you. We can't really help you with that unless you run into a specific problem along the way.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for a simple tool tip (Html default) you can try the below code.

Create a custom Dropdown helper method and add a atttribute for title. Using javascript mouseover you can display the item title.

```
"onmouseover","this.title=this.options[this.selectedIndex].title"

 public static MvcHtmlString DropDownList(this HtmlHelper htmlHelper, string name, IEnumerable<YourType> selectList)
        {
            var select = new TagBuilder("select");

            var options = "";
            TagBuilder option;

            foreach (var item in selectList)
            {
                option = new TagBuilder("option");
                option.MergeAttribute("value", item.Id.ToString());
                option.MergeAttribute("text", item.Title);
                option.MergeAttribute("title", item.Title);
                option.SetInnerText(item.Title);
                options += option.ToString(TagRenderMode.Normal) + "\n";
            }

            select.MergeAttribute("id", name);
            select.MergeAttribute("name", name);
            select.MergeAttribute("onmouseover","this.title=this.options[this.selectedIndex].title");
            select.InnerHtml = options;

            return new MvcHtmlString(select.ToString(TagRenderMode.Normal));
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use javascript/jquery to load the extra info. It is not that difficult. You just need find the html element by id or classname in js, then use ajax or razor to load the extra info for each option.